# How to embed a react.js project in an html page?

Tags: html, reactjs

I am creating a static html website with only one page to sponsor a collection of nft. The web page is simply structured by five sections and in one of them I have to insert a component created through react.js . I'm finding extreme difficulty to insert the react project inside the appropriate section of the site. I followed the simple tutorial in the official docs of react ( https://it.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html ), but it seems not to work and I can not understand why. Can anyone provide me with a different method or explanation?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Show what have you tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is my React's project folder :

[image: react-project-folder]

And this is the result :

[image: result-project]

I want to embed this grey react component inside a  in a simple html page.

First of all I've create a div with one id:

```
<div id="component-container"></div>
```

And I've added the tag scripts for load react in the html page (at the end of the body tag) and i've linked the App.js file (inside the /src folder in react):

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" 
  crossorigin> 
  </script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" 
  crossorigin></script>
```

At the end in the App.js file (inside the /src folder in react project), I've added this variable to be able to link the div I had created previously in the html page:

```
const contenitoreDom = document.querySelector('#component-container');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), contenitoreDom);
```

This is the react docs procedure ,but it doesn't seem to work, I can't figure out how to display a react component inside an externally created html page.
Thanks to all.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?